# Touchpad has stopped working in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

I have a thinkpad t460. This morning when I was using the touchpad it was working fine, I closed the lid, came back an hour later and the touchpad has stopped working.

I have tried restarting, trying a different kernel version but still the same problem.

Not entirely sure where to start on fixing this

It may be relevant to know that the red nipple thing in the middle works, which is how I am managing to navigate this site right now.

I also booted into Windows where the touchpad worked fine.

`xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]`

`synclient 
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`

`sudo modprobe -rv psmouse && sudo modprobe -v psmouse
rmmod psmouse
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko`

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the synaptics driver. What's the output of `xinput list`?

Comment: Thanks @AlcuinArundel - i have updated my question with the output, any ideas?

Comment: OK, that's good. Now do `synclient | grep Touchpad`

Comment: And another edit, this could be the problem i guess?

Comment: Indeed ... try `sudo modprobe -rv psmouse && sudo modprobe -v psmouse`

Comment: Hope that illuminates something..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42174/discussion-between-alcuin-arundel-and-qui).

Comment: Someone else was dealing with a similar issue yesterday and seems to have found a solution. Give it a shot: http://askubuntu.com/a/796183/381089

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, but sadly it's still broken. Tempted to do a clean install at this point although it seems a ridiculous solution.

Comment: Try asking on https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/  There are a lot of Linux users there who might be able to help.

Comment: Yeah! @AlcuinArundel I've had this problem for almost a year ;-)  `sudo modprobe -rv psmouse && sudo modprobe -v psmouse` fixes it and saves a reboot thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Anyone still experiencing this problem can try updating their kernel to the latest version, I tried everything else and that was the solution for me. Just use the commands

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.11.0-14-lowlatency linux-headers-4.11.0-14-lowlatency
```

Obviously this installs the 4.11.0.14 lowlatency kernel which is currently the latest but you can choose your version - usually pressing tab while at typing in the version gives some options. When booting it should automatically choose the newest **installed** kernel but you can otherwise select advanced ubuntu options from the grub boot menu and select the kernel from there.

Comment: Why is 4.11 "the latest". Latest for what? Why lowlatency? How is it related to the original question? Do you have the same touchpad?

Comment: as i said it was the latest kernel at the time of posting, its the latest because... well... its the latest i dont know what else to say there. There are 'lowlatency' and 'generic' versions of the kernel, my preliminary research seems to suggest that lowlatency has benefits with respect to low latency audio, and doesnt necessarily mean a faster kernel.  Also as i said this fixed my touchpad issues,  it seems as though some older versions of the kernel (around version 4.4.x but i cant pinpoint the exact version although i tried up to version 4.8.x unsuccessfully ) are having driver issues